# GitHub Action Error: Docker pull failed with exit code 1

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to run my `npm` build inside the docker container using our private docker image with GitHub actions.

My Workflow `yaml` file as follows,

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: Linux-self-hosted  # This is our self hosted linux runner system.
    container:
      image: ubuntu-20.04-lts:latest  # This is our private docker image.

    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Npm Build
      run: npm install

    - name: Build Package
      run: vsce package
```

**GitHub Action Error:-**

> Starting job container   /usr/bin/docker pull ubuntu-20.04-lts:latest
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ubuntu-20.04-lts,
> repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
> requested access to the resource is denied   Warning: Docker pull
> failed with exit code 1, back off 4.74 seconds before retry.
> /usr/bin/docker pull ubuntu-20.04-lts:latest   Error response from
> daemon: pull access denied for ubuntu-20.04-lts, repository does not
> exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the
> resource is denied   Warning: Docker pull failed with exit code 1,
> back off 9.535 seconds before retry.   /usr/bin/docker pull
> ubuntu-20.04-lts:latest   Error response from daemon: pull access
> denied for ubuntu-20.04-lts, repository does not exist or may require
> 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
> Error: Docker pull failed with exit code 1

i have this `ubuntu-20.04-lts:latest` private docker image on my host system locally. Still it fails with above error during action build.

It looks trying to connect docker hub. How do i fix this to use our local private image?

Comment: Not sure if you can use a local private image there. Do you also have that image in a registry? If so, try prefixing the image with the registry's name (you can also provide username/password as described here: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-24-github-actions-private-registry-support-for-job-and-service-containers/)

Comment: Currently the image is present in host system. Yet to be pushed to our private registry. Sure I will push the image in to our private registry and try.

Comment: @rethab, Thanks a lot.   Image needs to pushed to private registry and post that, In the `yaml` following needs to be added.    `credentials:`
        `username: mona`
        `password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password}}` example helped.

Comment: Nice :) I have added it as an answer so we can mark this question as resolved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to push your image to your private registry. Once it is there, you can configure the credentials for your private registry as described in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainercredentials):

```yaml
container:
  image: ghcr.io/owner/image
  credentials:
     username: ${{ github.actor }}
     password: ${{ secrets.ghcr_token }}
```